# Protractor - Microsoft Edge on MacOs (Not able to automate)

Tags: javascript, protractor, microsoft-edge, browser-automation

Hi community: I have a project in Protractor which have 4 browsers... Let's make a long short story. Microsoft Edge does not run in Protractor.

I already have installed Microsoft Edge.

```
Microsoft Edge is up to date.
Version 83.0.478.54 (Official build) (64-bit)
```

This is a part from my **protractor.conf.js**

```
multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--disable-gpu']
      }},
    {browserName: 'firefox',
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        args: ['--incognito']
      }},
    {browserName: 'safari',
      'safari.options': {
        args: ['--incognito']
      }},
      {browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
      'edge.options': {
        args: ['--incognito']
      }}],

  directConnect: false, 
  baseUrl: 'https://www.xxxxxx.com', 

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
```

The error displays the next:

```
[MicrosoftEdge #11] /Users/rxxxxxxxx/WebstormProjects/protractor_automation/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546
[MicrosoftEdge #11]         throw new ctor(message);
[MicrosoftEdge #11]               ^
[MicrosoftEdge #11] SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: EdgeDriverService
[MicrosoftEdge #11] Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
[MicrosoftEdge #11] System info: host: 'XXXXXXXXXX', ip: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
[MicrosoftEdge #11] Driver info: driver.version: unknown
...
[MicrosoftEdge #11]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[MicrosoftEdge #11] From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
....
[13:34:32] E/launcher - Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
```

I already downloaded the msedgedriver and place it to the next folder:

```
/Users/rxxxxxxxx/WebstormProjects/protractor_automation/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/msedgedriver
```

Can anybody help me, please?

UPDATE:

**Protractor version: 7.0.0**

Comment: when you say you installed microsoft edge, you mean the browser itself or the driver?

Comment: Hi Sergey: The browser installed. The driver is in the path above.

Comment: which protractor version are you using?

Comment: so what I was gonna do to debug is to go to `/Users/rxxxxxxxx/WebstormProjects/protractor_automation/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js` line `546` and see what's is the condition this error is thrown, but I don't have that file... Either somehow my installation is different or by some mistake the program point to the wrong place and causes the error. In first case, just open that file yourself and try to back-engineer

Comment: Protractor 7.0.0

Comment: Line 546: throw new ctor(message); that is the error

Comment: right Line 546 is the error itself, but take a look at how the code got into this line... eg it may have a condition like `if (/* edge driver is present */)` or `if (/* edge driver version === 'something else' */)`

Comment: Please make sure the webdriver version corresponds to the version of Edge you having. Also please make sure that you have added Java to your **PATH** because webdriver-manager needs it for Edge. Besides, I found [an article](https://www.sep.com/sep-blog/2020/01/29/how-to-run-protractor-e2e-tests-in-microsoft-edge-chromium/) about running Protractor tests in Microsoft Edge Chromium which you could refer to. You could try to add individual config files and add the commands to `package.json` like the article says.

Comment: Yes, actually the driver corresponds with the Edge version.

Comment: Please check if you're using the right webdriver version. Download the Mac version in [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/). I saw `Driver info: driver.version: unknown` in the error message like the webdriver is not recognized or incompatible so I think the issue is related with the webdriver version and ask you to make sure again.

Comment: Hi Yu: I already downloaded the driver and it matches with the Edge browser installed. By other hand, the java version is already present in my bash profile.

Comment: @nosequeweaponer in the support browser list: https://www.protractortest.org/#/browser-support I didn't find Microsoft Edge there

Comment: Elvis Xia: Put that same comment as answer for accepting that.

Comment: @nosequeweaponer Done.

Comment: Hello @nosequeweaponer, I have the same problem. Have you solve this issue? Or is it not possible to run protractor tests in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Hi Alfredo: That's not possible. https://www.protractortest.org/#/browser-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Protractor Supported Browsers](https://www.protractortest.org/#/browser-support), Microsoft Edge is currently not supported by Protractor.

You can raise an Feature Request to [Protractor Github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues).

Answer (score 0):

There is slightly different flow of running Chromium Edge browser, regular edge driver is not applicable.

Check this article - you need to download special chromium edge driver and set path to it in capabilities:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=javascript